# Внешний вид страницы в браузере андроида Google Chrome

Tags: css, reactjs, google-chrome, scss

Есть простая страница с 3-мя элементами в низу. С компьютера в консоли для телефона все выглядит корректно[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKUXG.png).
Так же на айфоне в браузере Google Chrome[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5030.jpg).
Но на андроиде в браузере при открытой плашке меню браузера сверху[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nh2Bt.jpg) - элементы внизу не видно - страница выглядит нормально только при закрытии этого меню[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZDgG.jpg).
Как это исправить ?

Структура[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4f6m.png);
Стили[6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvH3Y.png).

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А где ваш код? Он должен быть в вопросе и текстом

Comment: @SwaD, на код на скриншотах есть ответ на видео)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так используй `svh` ([подробнее](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ru3U8MHbFFI)). А лучше вообще проценты.